# как реализовать конструкицию типа v.resize<20>() через шаблон?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Необходимо изменить размерность вектора v через шаблон, чтобы получился вызов такого типа v.resize<20>(). Как это объявить в классе с++?

Comment: кому необходимо, какого вектора?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверняка это для проверки вашего знания о том, что  наследник есть разновидность типа и наследует все открытые члены, с возможностью изменить их(или спрятать).

```
template <class T>
struct Vector :
    public std::vector<T> 
{   
    template <size_t n>
    void resize() { this->resize(n); }
};

int main() {    
    Vector<int> v;
    v.resize<5>();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Применять ООП принцицы к классам из стандартной библиотеки вобщем случае не очень корреткно. Там же всё на шаблонах.

Comment: А в этом абстрактном примере может и сойдет если предположить что архитектура проекта не нарушается и там всего пару сотен строк кода. Но я к примеру ни разу в реальных проектах не видел расширение стандартных шаблонных классов.

Comment: @ampawd Шаблоны не мешают наследованию. Некоторые не любят наследоваться от стандартных контейнеров, потому что волнуются, что кто-то удалит такого потомка через указатель на родителя, у которого нет виртуального деструктора. Но проблема выглядит немного надуманно, на попытку это сделать должен быть ворнинг.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat не мешают но согласитесь что разумнее было бы аггрегировать std::vector в другой класс создав там этот шаблонный resize.

Comment: @ampawd Зависит от того, какая стоит задача. Если хочется повторить интерфейс, но с одним измененным методом, то проще унаследоваться (и хорошо бы еще унаследовать конструкторы). А если весь интерфейс кастомный, то да, можно и член.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat даже вспомнить не могу примеры из реальных проектов где требовалось повторить интерфейс стандратных классов.

Comment: в основном свои кастомные вектора строки и т.д. пишут, нежели их расширяют

Comment: господа комментаторы, не думаете ли вы, что этот вопрос для серьезного проекта? Обсуждать о космосе хорошо если создаем телескоп, но если делаем игрушку, причем тут космос?...

Comment: Спасибо большое всем за помощь! Это задание было частью университетской лабораторной работы, поэтому достаточно всего лишь повторить конструкцию из условия. Спасибо за Ваши советы, я их учту!